# Change color of the field when condition is satisfied

Tags: extjs

For example, I have textfield with input type 'email'. I have set the default color of the field to pink. if the input is in a proper email format, i want the textfield's color to be changed to white. how do i do that?

the eg code:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
labelWidth : 250,
fieldStyle: 'background-color : #F5A9A9',
vtype :  'email',
fieldLabel: 'email address'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case first we need to check weather input value is an email or not. For that we are using 
`var fieldValidation =  Ext.form.field.VTypes.email(val);`
If **fieldValidation** is true then it input value is an email. Once we verified input value simply we change our background color. `this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #FFFFFF")`

Your code will like :

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
         fieldStyle: 'background-color : #F5A9A9',
        vtype :  'email',
        fieldLabel: 'email address',
        validator : function(val){
        var fieldValidation =  Ext.form.field.VTypes.email(val);
           if(fieldValidation == true){
              this.setFieldStyle("background-color : #FFFFFF");
           }
        }
    }
```

I created a fiddle for you. Please have a look. [Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1stu).

Also I am attaching doc of Vtype for you which help you understand properly. [Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html#method-email)